# Use of bitmaps increases RAM usage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, android-image

I'm develoving an Android App, where have two activities that use a RecyclerView with a customized layout that contains images.
To load the images, I have:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.led);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

I thought that at the onDestroy() method of the activity, if the images were loaded as Bitmaps the GC would be able to free some space, however this is not happening and the usage of RAM memory increases until the app crashes for an OOM error.

Could anyone help me to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Add a call to recycle for bitmaps, Android doesn't automatically release them

Comment: Here's a question. Why don't you use imgView.setImageDrawable() ? You don't need to decode a drawable to a bitmap to set it into an ImageView.

Comment: do you need to convert drawable into bitmap? android shares drawable to views which have same drawable.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Android does recycle Bitmaps automatically, but it's still a good idea to call `recycle()` if you're not using a `Bitmap` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a bitmap for only displaying drawable resource to the ImageView. You can directly do that!

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.led);
```

Comment: And when do I need to use Bitmap? To load an image saved in the device giving the path?

Comment: @mireia Your initial question is about the drawable images. Add another question as **displaying the local device image to the RecyclerView**.